# Checking if record exists SQL for PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, sql, cordova

I am needing to find out if a record exists, so that I am able to update or delete it.

Seeing as to the best of my knowledge, everything required a transaction, selecting a count will not work.

There is hardly any documentation I can find that is usefull, the current code i have is:

```
app.database.db.transaction(function (tx) {
    $.each(result.specoffer, function (i, item) {
        if (typeof item.id != 'undefined') {
            var sql = '' +
            'IF EXISTS SELECT id FROM Specials WHERE id = ' + item.id + ' ' +
            'UPDATE Specials SET picture = "' + item.picture + '", startdate = "test", finishdate = "test", mess = "' + item.mess + '", shortmess = "' + item.picture +
            '", shortmess = "' + item.shortmess + '", name = "' + name + '" WHERE id = '                 + item.id + ' ' +
            'ELSE ' +
            'INSERT INTO Specials (id, picture, startdate, finishdate, mess, shortmess, name) VALUES (' +
            item.id + ', "' + item.picture + '", "test", "test", "' + item.mess + '", "'                 + item.shortmess + '", "' + item.name + '")';

            tx.executeSql(sql);
        } 
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: How are you accessing your database from Javascript client side directly? I think you need to create an API that your client side can talk to. Can you post a bit more detail on your project setup please? Thanks.

Comment: It is phonegap storage, http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html it communicates to local storage on the device. It was a W3C standard but was phased out. http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/ 

However Phonegap still uses it and you can use it for smartphones to save data locally.

Comment: i am retrieving data from a server with jsonp every 10 to 15 mins, i put that into local store to save round trips or the user looses wifi. It's a pretty mean setup really you need to have it for any decent mobile app, i'm not sure why there isn't more people with the same issue.

Comment: i guess i'll have to end up deleting them and re-adding, it's not perfect but it should do the job

Comment: We use localStorage (as opposed to Webdatabase) for that sort of thing, and when the user goes back online, we will update localStorage. So, localStorage just acts like a trivial cache.

Comment: i considered that but i like the ability to be able to select by id for products details and ordering by date. however no dobut in my mind that it could be done with localStorage too

Answer (score 1):

You can use Update or Delete directly

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('UPDATE Category SET categoryName="' + categoryName
                + '",categoryIconPath="' + categoryIconPath
                + '",categoryDescription="' + categoryDescription
                + '" WHERE categoryId=' + categoryId + '', [], function(tx,
                result) {

        }, errorCB);
```

Just put your table name and columns respectively. Here categoryId is unique like item.Id in your case